# Drupal - Simple Edit can't find

Tags: ssl, drupal-7, vimeo

Ok, I have been searching for days on how to fix the vimeo urls on this page:  https://www.createjobsforusa.org

Basically, I just got an SSL certificate and I'd like to change `http://{the vimeo url}` vimeo linking videos to `https://{the vimeo url}` Simple edit is all I need, but I can't find where the videos are located.

Content Blocks? All I get are settings for this. Pages? So, I go to "Content" and I see a huge list of pages in there, I see a page called "Home", so I click on the `Edit` link and the body of the page is blank? Ok, so this has to be coming from someplace else, but where?

Can someone please help me with how to find the vimeo video URLs and change them to "https://" instead of "http://"

I think the View is called: A-Spots... here are pics of what I get when I click on the Edit A-Spot View:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What exactly am I supposed to do here? Seems like so much to do, but every option I seem to choose still doesn't give me the option to change the vimeo URLs.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this?  Just trying to find out where to look for the vimeo links here.  Is that such a non-worthy question?

Comment: Since the site is using the Views module, I would look at the view used for the front page, and which nodes is showing. One of those is the node that you need to edit.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the View is called:  `A-Spots`, but how to edit it?  I click on the Edit button to the right under Operations for that view, and I get another page, which seems to look like permissions for that view... WTF?  Will attach a pic of it now to my question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Under Content at the bottom (in the last pic), it just displays like 3 groups of numbers.  Not sure what that is supposed to be.  I can't edit any of this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view just select nodes (or other entities) to show them. If you edit a view, you just change the way those nodes are selected or shown; you don't edit the nodes a view selects to show.

If you look at the preview of that view, you will notice it shows some numbers; those numbers are node IDs. Just edit the node from https://www.createjobsforusa.org/node/55291246/edit; replace 55291246 with the other IDs shown, and you will be able to edit all the nodes used from the view.
If that doesn't work, https://www.createjobsforusa.org/admin/content lists all the content in the site. Just look for the nodes whose ID is the one shown in that preview, and edit them.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've managed to edit the node, but it seems that it's linked into a `Content Type` and 1 of the fields are the vimeo ID.  But I don't need to change the vimeo ID, I need to change the `http://` to `https://' for this part:  `http://player.vimeo.com/video/`  I believe somewhere is a global setting for this, either in a file or in the database... don't know where to look for that.  Because all I can change when editing the nodes are the Vimeo ID numbers, not the actual URLs!

Comment: Yes, I found it, thanks.  It was in a file.  When I clicked on the Advanced section of the Views, and on `Information` it lead me to the actual file where the php code was being outputted.  Cheers :)